# Why is Internet Explorer (8) thinking this is XML

Tags: xml, internet-explorer-8, ihttphandler, response.contenttype

This is the Raw response that is generated from the server (using Fiddler2)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
MS-Author-Via: MS-FP/4.0
Date: Fri, 10 Dec 2010 18:19:18 GMT
Content-Length: 594

Contents of 24194_XXXXXXXXXX.log as of 10/12/2010 19:19:18
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : START: New Alarm [9]
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 12/10/2010 19:14:56 - <?xml version="1.0"?>
<CALLS>
  <CALL>
    <CALL_ID>9_1</CALL_ID>
    <BODY>004|007|015|058|1_ToConfirm|2_ToDecline</BODY>
    <LANGID>321</LANGID>
    <TO1>99999999999</TO1>
    <TO2 />
  </CALL>
</CALLS>
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : END: New Alarm [9]
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 12/10/2010 19:15:30 - <RESULT><CALL_ID>9_1</CALL_ID><CALLRESULT1>0</CALLRESULT1><DTMF1>2</DTMF1><CALLRESULT2></CALLRESULT2><DTMF2></DTMF2></RESULT>
```

In my asp.net `IHttpHandler` I have set

```
           context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
```

Which it is clearly returning. In IE8 I get to see this:
[image: IE8 trying to be clever...]

When I try the **Save Target As...**  I get this (Notice the **Save as type:**):
[image]

Comment: I guess it's simply because IE decides not to obey the given content-type and instead of this starts to parse the content,  finds the xml header and that's it. Why should the IE suddenly behave like it's written in some exotic standards :-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is kind of notorious for second-guessing the content type. Presumably they're doing content-sniffing and the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` is tripping it up.

Try using a different content type other than text/plain or application/octet-stream to see if you get the same behavior. It's looks like it only does the sniffing for those two types in an attempt to work around misconfigured web servers:

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(VS.85).aspx#introduction

Comment: I initially suggested trying application/octet-stream instead of text/plain. That was a bad idea, as those two types are both considered "ambiguous" by IE. So something completely different like application/x-logfile might be better.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using the Content-disposition as http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519

Comment: Does IE9 still ruddy content sniff pages even after an explicit content-type set?

Answer (score 0):

It's looking at your actual content which has xml in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

It's easy to understand why when you don't have any html elements such as html, head, or body.  If you want the xml to be displayed as text then you will need to include in html and escape the markup properly.

Comment: Thanks, I understand, it is trying to be 'clever'. But it's a simple text log file which happens to contain some xml fragments. I do not want to convert is to xml. Just want to see the text. (IE should do the decent thing and open notepad - really)